# Python Script Only Reads 100 First Files

Tags: python, word-frequency

I have a folder with 616 files, but my script only reads the first 100. What settings do I need to change around to get it to read them all? It's probably relevant, I'm using Anaconda Navigator's Jupyter Notebook.

Here's my code:

```
import re
import string
from collections import Counter
import os
import glob

def word_count(file_tokens):
    for word in file_tokens:
        count = Counter(file_tokens)
    return count

files_list = glob.glob("german/test/*/negative/*")
print(files_list)
for path in files_list:
    corpus, tache, classe, file_name = path.split("\\")
    file = open(path, mode="r", encoding="utf-8")
    read_file = file.read()

    ##lowercase
    file_clean = read_file.lower()


    ##tokenize
    file_tokens = file_clean.split()

    ##word count and sort
    print(word_count(file_tokens))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried printing the length of the `files_list` variable and check if it is 616 or 100 ?

```
print(len(files_list))
```

Comment: it says there are 618 files (i added a file and also miscounted, there should be 617), but when i run the script, it's only running it on the first 100

Comment: Does it throw any exceptions? Or does it stop with no error?

Comment: It seems to have fixed itself, it's now returning all the information

Answer (score 1):

You are probably hitting some max open files limit in your system. You can either `close` every file at the end of the loop, or use a context manager in the loop:

```
with open(path, mode="r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    ....
```